# Jmeter scripting - how to capture value from drop down list?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to create script for one of my application. The application contains customer profile details. Few fields are present in the form of drop down list. I should correlate values that i select from the dropdown list. Below is one sample field:

-- Select --
EMPLOYEE
NORMAL

Here i need to select NORMAL which means i should capture the value NORMAL and replace it in the script.I have captured the entire list from "-- Select --
EMPLOYEE
NORMAL" in a variable and used split function to capture NORMAL from the captured value. but i am unable to capture the value NORMAL correctly. Can anyone please explain me how split function works in jmeter and what unique value should i put as seperator to capture the selected value NORMAL.

Please let me know how can this be achieved.

Thanks in Advance,

Gayathri

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the manual on the split function? 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split

```
Example:
Define SOURCE="a||c|" in the test plan.
${__split(${SOURCE},SPLIT),|}
This will return the contents of VAR, i.e. "a||c|" and set the following variables:
SPLIT_n=4 (3 in JMeter 2.1.1 and earlier)
SPLIT_1=a
SPLIT_2=?
SPLIT_3=c
SPLIT_4=? (null in JMeter 2.1.1 and earlier)
SPLIT_5=null (in JMeter 2.1.2 and later)
```

In your case, to get "normal", you'd want to reference ${SPLIT_3}

Depending on the source code, it might be easier to write a regex to extract your value:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor